# Finding file name οf currently open file in vi on terminal

Tags: command-line, vi

How do I check the file name that is open in the terminal? That is, how do I check which file is open now in the terminal?

Now whenever I want to see the file name I have to exit and then have to check. Is there a way to check the current file name in the terminal?

Comment: if the file is open, then you must be reading it with some program. How are you opening the file?

Comment: using vi editor , but once I open the file I could not see file name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `:f`. It will display the filename as well as extra info:

[image]

You can also use `:args` to see what filenames as command line arguments were given to vim. This is convenient when you want to know which of the buffers you are using, if you opened multiple files (the current one is enclosed in brackets):

[image]

Answer (score 14):

To see the filename in vi(m) press <kbd>esc</kbd> and then type

```
:set title
```

The filename appears in the top bar of the terminal window. You can also do

```
:buffers
```

to see the file(s) currently open - the information is displayed inside the terminal at the bottom. If you have multiple files open, you can tell which one you are in as `%a`  is shown beside the current file, for example

```
:buffers
  1 %a=   "unicorns"      line 19     
  2       "rainbows"      line 1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: And it might be a great idea  to simply add `set title` in the ~/.vimrc configuration file....

Answer (score 9):

I prefer Ctrl-G:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html

```
CTRL-G      or              *CTRL-G* *:f* *:fi* *:file*
:f[ile]         Prints the current file name (as typed, unless ":cd"
            was used), the cursor position (unless the 'ruler'
            option is set), and the file status (readonly,
            modified, read errors, new file).  See the 'shortmess'
            option about how to make this message shorter.
            {Vi does not include column number}
```

Answer (score 8):

The filename of the currently edited file is in the `%` register. You can view it with `:reg %`.

Answer (score 1):

I like a lot the [**status line**](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Displaying_status_line_always): `set laststatus=2`  (or `set ls=2`)

[image: vim status line screenshot]

As you see, among other useful info like current mode, file status, ruler, etc. the status line displays the full path of the currently opened file.

See [:help laststatus](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27laststatus%27) for more details.

[*thanks Sven](http://www.guckes.net/vim/setup.html)

---

I like to see the status line at any time, so I added the above instruction to my `vim` local configuration:

```
 sudo sh -c "echo 'set ls=2' >> ~/.vimrc"
```

Comment: Ah, i see. The status line contains the name of the file. Good ! But you might edit your answer to actually explain why status line is necessary. First time I read your answer , I was confused , so a lot of people probably will be confused too. You need to edit for clarity

Comment: Also it's not necessary to set it in `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`. Set it in your `~/.vimrc` will be sufficient. `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` is pretty much global, for all users